# Answer Set Program to SAT translation

Tags: satisfiability, constraint-satisfaction, answer-set-programming

During the presentation (a talk) [Answer Set Programming: Boolean Constraint Solving for Knowledge Representation and Reasoning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVQ0bP8zyHw) Torsten Schaub (University of Postdam) stated [around twenty-one minutes into the talk](https://youtu.be/gVQ0bP8zyHw?t=1250), "You can't translate an ASP (answer set program) into SAT (propositional formula) in a modular way...." continuing... "If you don't extend the language and if you translate ASP into SAT you risk an exponential blowup."

Is there an example that clearly shows that Answer Set Program to SAT translation is exponential.

PS: Allowed to use [Plaisted Greenbaum encoding](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717186800281?via%3Dihub) or [Tseitin transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation).

Comment: factoring? or NP complete problem instances?

Comment: @vzn I am dealing with an NP-complete problem.